# latex missing "\item" when using itemize

Tags: errors, lists, itemize

I am tryint to add a list of items in a latex document. I currently have this setup:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size


\begin{itemize}
\Item this is not a test
\end{itemize}
```

or

```
\begin{itemize}
\item this is not a test
\end{itemize}
```

I get this error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
Overfull \hbox (26.52249pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 61--67
[][]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.81 \Item
           this is not a test
```

How come I keep getting compile errors when I add this list to my document?

It was not a typo, I was just trying to express that I tried \item and \Item and they both gave me the same error.

I wanted a bullet list inside of a tabular section. I got around it by copy pasting a bullet and using a footnote sized text.

```
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
\emph{Jun 2010 - Current} & Soccer Player at \textsc{University of ...}, City, Country \\
& \footnotesize {An excellent forward and some more stuff.... }\\\\
& \footnotesize {• bullet list item one} \\
& \footnotesize {• bullet list item two} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

%a few more items
\end{tabular}
```

it wasn't clear that you couldn't just add an itemized list between the begin and end tabular section so the latex compiler was throwing errors referring to the item.

Comment: Well, LaTeX is case sensitive and the only valid form is `\item` (with a lowercase `i`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem stems from a simple typo.

Comment: It's not a typo, I've tried both item and Item that's what the code sample was showing.

Comment: That is why you always prepare and test a full minimal example

Comment: This question is very confused, but it has an useful answer (`itemize` in tabular). What about rewriting it for the future users?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
\emph{Jun 2010 - Current} & Soccer Player at \textsc{University of ...}, City, Country \\
  &  \begin{itemize}
    \item An excellent forward and some more stuff
    \item bullet list item one
    \item bullet list item two
  \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\Item` is not the same as `\item`.

Do not use uppercase in a command when it should be lowercase and the error will be removed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item this is not a test
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually tracked down the error, it wasn't a typo. I was showing that I've tried Item and item. The true issue was that the You cannot add an itemized list inside of a tabular section in any simple lay to get a bullet list.