# Confusing "missing \item" error from itemize

Tags: errors, itemize, minipage

Why does an `itemize` section inside of a `minipage` section raises `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item` despite that not being the case?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.35\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item my first item
\end{itemize}

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.65\textwidth}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019 Gentoo Linux)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.073 seconds
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./test.aux)

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.6 \item m
         y first item
? X
 545 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 rule, 2 local_par, 2 dir, 1 glue, 3 kern, 8 glyph, 4 attribute, 6
1 glue_spec, 4 attribute_list, 3 temp, 4 if_stack, 1 shape, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 3:2,4:1,7:1,9:1

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

This looks similar to [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290857/latex-missing-item-when-using-itemize) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503467/tabularx-and-itemize-missing-item) I found, but in my case I'm not using `tabular`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `itemize` doesn't take an optional argument. Remove the `[nosep]` to make your example compile.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I was following examples in (this documentation)[https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf] which do give an optional argument. But after reading your comment I noticed that there is a (known bug)[http://www.texnia.com/enumitem.html]  around `nosep` not being reliable. Removing the `nosep` argument fixes my issue.

Comment: Your test document compiles just fine if you add the instruction `\usepackage{enumitem}` to the preamble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you encounter can also be generated by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item my first item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

As you've already discovered, the real source of the error is the failure to load the `enumitem` package. The `enumitem` package, and not the LaTeX kernel, defines the optional setting `nosep`.

Nevertheless, it may be instructive to trace *why* LaTeX would issue the following messages when running the MWE shown above:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \item m
           y first item
?
```

If the `enumitem` package is *not* loaded, LaTeX requires the very first item [pun intended] after `\begin{itemize}` to be `\item`. Thus, because the material in square brackets is not preceded by an `\item` statement in the MWE, LaTeX gets confused and stops with an admittedly not particularly clear error message.

Incidentally, if one inserts an `\item` directive immediately before `[nosep]`, i.e., if one changes the MWE to

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}\item[nosep]
\item my first item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX runs just fine and the word "nosep" shows up as the substitute for the default level-1 marker (which happens to be a text bullet):

[image]

Finally, as already noted, it's essential to load the `enumitem` package in order to get the expected behavior from the `[nosep]` option.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation

Answer (score 0):

Loading `enumitem` resolves the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.35\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item my first item
\end{itemize}

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.65\textwidth}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```